# Pytest best practice to setup and teardown before and after all tests

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Got a pytest script containing roughly 50 tests in 5 different files.

I need to setup a setup function that will run once before test are ran and then another one after all test are done ( pass or fail )

For some weird reason I have tried with pytest_sessionstart and pytest_sessionfinish but only the sessionfinish I can't find how to have the sessionstart ran. They are located in contest.py in same folder as my test_ files.

I have ran pytest --debug, I can see the sessionstart hook but for some reason the function is not executed. Pytest documentation is not so clear about what best practice to use, does anyone have any recommendations as to why my sessionstart function is not ran or how should I use it.

Again I don't want this run before and after every test, only once before first test and once after last test.

If I try the following code but it seems fixture are not ran at all :

```
import pytest

def pytest_sessionstart():
    print("In pytest_sessionstart")

def pytest_sessionfinish():
    print("In pytest_sessionfinish")

def pytest_configure():
    print("In pytest_configure")

def pytest_addoption():
    print("In pytest_addoption")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def fixture_scope_session():
    print("Beginning of fixture")
    yield
    print("End of fixture")

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def between_test():
    print("Between test")
```

Would give the following output :

```
(testenv) C:\Users\dfasdfasd\Documents\Project\pytesttest>pytest
In pytest_configure
In pytest_sessionstart
============================ test session starts ====================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: C:\Users\dfasdfasd\Documents\Project\pytesttest
collected 4 items

test_test\test_2.py ..                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     [ 50%] 
test_test\test_3.py ..                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     [100%]In pytest_sessionfinish


================= 4 passed in 0.03s ===============
```

How come addoption is not ran ?
How come fixtures are not ran ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   In Stack Overflow, you need to show your code, not tell us about what it does.  Please include relevant parts of your code, the expected output of the tests and the actual output of the tests.

Comment: @ewokx to add to this. Do not post your production code. Create a *minimal* example which can reproduce the behavior you find confusing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ewokx  edited first post thank you

Answer (score 3):

The best practice for setup and teardown that run once during whole test run is usage of "session" scope fixture. You should not use hooks for it.

In your case I believe you just need to create `conftest.py` file in your tests root directory. Then you add some function that you must decorate with `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")`.

Your setup and teardown must be separated with `yield` statement like this:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def some_function_name():
    print("this is setup")
    yield
    print("this is teardown")
```

Do not forget to request this fixture in every test that needs these setup and teardown. If you need it for all of your tests without any exceptions then you may use flag `autouse=True` as `pytest.fixture` argument. However, I do not recommend to use it because it makes your code a bit harder to debug.

Please note that it will be executed only once per whole test run. That's because we use scope "session".

You can read more about fixture scopes here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session

**UPD:**

```
pytest test_2.py -s

In pytest_addoption

In pytest_configure   
                      
In pytest_sessionstart
==== test session starts ===
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\repos\pytest_imports
configfile: pyproject.toml
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

test_2.py
Beginning of fixture

Between test

test1
.
Between test

test2
.
End of fixture

In pytest_sessionfinish
```

Comment: The trick is I don't want setup and teardown at EACH test, I want setup before all test, teardown at the end of all test.

Comment: I did try using scope="session" edited first post but it's not ran :(

Comment: It is working as you want it. Just add `-s` to your pytest run to see print outputs

Comment: @Wizardry I have updated my answer adding output of your code with "session" scope fixture. And about your first comment - you really need to go through pytest docs to understand how fixture scopes works. "Setup and teardown at EACH test" - is function scope fixture. Scope "session" will reuse returned value from first fixture request for each following request in whole test run.